# multipling two edit text

Tags: java, android

I am trying to multiply two EditText, both editHours and editWage and display results in a TextView (gross) any help is much appreciated

```
public class PayrollActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

 TextView gross, net, calculated;
 EditText editHours, editWage;
 int hours, wage, intGross, intNet, pay;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_payroll);


     gross = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gross);
     hours= Integer.parseInt(editHours.getText().toString());
     wage = Integer.parseInt(editWage.getText().toString());
     gross.setText(hours*wage);
     net = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.net);
     calculated = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calculated);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton)).setOnClickListener(new     OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("It worked");
             calculated.setText(str);
         }
     });    
    }
```

The app is crashing at

```
hours= Integer.parseInt(editHours.getText().toString());
```

LogCat

```
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659): Process: co.mytms.payroll, PID: 1659
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.mytms.payroll/co.mytms.payroll.PayrollActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at co.mytms.payroll.PayrollActivity.onCreate(PayrollActivity.java:22)
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-26 14:08:36.591: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: what problem are you having?

Comment: My app crashes at'code' hours= Integer.parseInt(editHours.getText().toString()); 'code

Comment: 'crashes at'. stacktrace?

Comment: first thing. have you provided inputtype in edittext inputType? Use it as a precaution. And what is the Exception name?

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems.

Firstly when calling the `getText()` method on your `EditText`s in `onCreate` they are still empty (and uninitialized see @Manishika [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23875554/1587046)). So `Integer.parseInt` will try to parse an empty `String`. Move this into the `onClick` method of the button, this is the behavior you want (i.e when you click on it, it multiplies the two values of both `EditText` and set the result to the `TextView`).

Secondly when doing `gross.setText(hours*wage);`, you will call the `setText` method that takes an `int` as parameter. The Android system will try to load the approriate `String` whose id corresponds to the one you defined in your `strings.xml` file. You need to call the method that accepts a `CharSequence` as argument. So do `gross.setText(String.valueOf(hours*wage));`

Also it's always good to add the stacktrace in your question, as it helps others to find faster your mistake.

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized your `EditTexts` before getting texts from them

```
editHours = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editHours_id);
editWage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editWage_id);
```

And also put your calculation inside onClick as initally it will return nothing but empty string.

```
 ((Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton)).setOnClickListener(new     OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

//If your input contains decimal values also then use BigDecimal() 
//Following code will work for both int and decimal values
gross.setText(""+new BigDecimal(editHours.getText()
                        .toString()).multiply(new BigDecimal(editWage.getText()
                        .toString())));
                 StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("It worked");
                 calculated.setText(str);



             }
         });
```

Comment: +1 Good catch for the uninitialized values :)

Comment: Thank you Manishika this solved my problem, but now it crashes if the input is a decimal

Comment: Try my updated code.this should work